Problem scaling a grid of buttons in a C# Winforms app
I'm working on a WinForms application in C# that dynamically generates a grid of buttons at runtime. The application runs fine on a PC monitor with 100% scaling, but when I run it on my laptop's display (which has 125% scaling), the layout doesn't adjust properly, and the buttons appear misaligned or stretched.
What I've Tried:

I set dpiAware to true and dpiAwareness to PerMonitorV2 in the app.manifest file.
I've also tried setting AutoScaleMode to Font and Dpi on the main form. (currently it is Font)

I tried multiple solutions related to this on StackOverflow.
Including:

Windows Forms DPI scaling and few others

documentation from Microsoft here


and few other similar solutions.
However, none of these changes resolved the issue.
--
How it looks on PC monitor using 100% scaling

How it looks on laptop with a single monitor using 125% scaling

Are there additional steps or settings in WinForms I should be using to fix this?
Any guidance, links to articles, or resources would be greatly appreciated.
[Edit] I use .Net 4.8.
Using auto size, as mentioned in @Jimi's comment below, makes some buttons grow. I prefer to scale or "normalize" the content inside the button, i.e., scale the font size to keep the buttons looking the same.
Is it possible?

You forgot to mention the .NET Framework version you're targeting -- PerMonitorV2 DpiAwareness is set in the app.config file (in .NET Framework, assuming 4.7.0+ / but actually working correctly in 4.7.1+) -- The image you posted shows the result of an app that's not DpiAware (clearly virtualized)

You're scaling to Font, but you're not letting the Controls auto-size to their content. Not clear how the grid of Buttons is generated; if you haven't, you should try with a TableLayoutPanel, set to auto-size itself, with Rows / Columns also set to auto-size. This of course requires that the Application is designed, from the start, to handle high-dpi scaling, so the User Interface dynamically adapts to changes in size of the child Controls, while maintaining its aspect. Implies the use of nested containers, wise anchoring / docking and a lot of testing in different monitors

Thanks, Jimi, see my edit.. using auto-size makes some buttons grow. I prefer to keep the unified button size and scale the label/font size inside.

So, why don't you set AutoScaleMode to DPI instead of Font?

I tried AutoScaleMode = DPI, but it didn't make any difference

How is the Font handled in those Buttons? Is it inherited (hierarchically), or set directly (independently from the Parent's) Or are they child Controls of a UserControl, and you have set the AutoScaleMode of the Form, but not the UC? Can you post some code that reproduces the Layout (including the Containers' layout)? When you say [...] a monitor using 125% scaling, what is scaled there, just the Font, the Screen size or both?

Scaling to Font is simpler, if you setup the Form (and nested containers) to dynamically grow and shrink, otherwise it's harder to work out. Scaling to DPI is simpler if you scale the Font yourself (handle the Form's DpiChanged and the Controls' DpiChangedAfterParent events). In all cases, careful design is required, as well as docking / anchoring and, as mentioned, wise use of nested containers which can auto-scale / auto-size. No magic wand here
